# Change default auth guard name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The default auth guard name in Laravel is 'web', but I found this confusing as it's provider is 'users'. Especially because for the admin guard the name is `admin` and the provider is `admins` (I'm using this for Nova). I'm on Laravel 6.5.2.

So I wanted to change this. In my `config/auth` I have:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'user',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

and

```
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

     'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ]
],
```

and

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

In `App\Models\User` I have

```
protected $guard = 'user';
```

In `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` I have

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest:user')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}
```

Now I get the error `Auth guard [web] is not defined` when logging in. Is it a bad idea to change it from `web` to `user`?

I found setting up the guards quite confusing, because you can define things in:

- config/auth
- In the model (`protected $guard = 'guard_name';`)
- In the LoginController, RegisterController and ResetPasswordController as per the Laravel docs (protected `function guard() { return Auth::guard('guard-name');}`)

In [this article](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel) it's described that it's possible to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please try to clear cache `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: Tried that, as well as `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`, didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because in the default `app/Providers/Route service provider.php` class, there is this method that registers your `roites/web.php` file with the `web` middleware. You should change the middleware name here as well:

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Comment: Changing `web` to `user` there gives `Target class [user] does not exist.`. I'm starting to think the conclusion is that it was indeed a bad idea to change it.

Comment: yeah this would just change what middleware group to us.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sanctum, make sure to add

`'guard' => 'user',`

to your `sanctum.php` config file.

You'll then need to run `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

1. Change app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected $namespaceUser = 'App\Http\Controllers\User';

public function boot()
{
   ...

   $this->routes(function () {
            
   Route::middleware('user')
       ->namespace($this->namespaceUser)
       ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        ...
    });
}
```

2. Redefine **guard()** function on **LoginController.php**

```
protected function guard()
{
   return Auth::guard('user');
}
```